# Google Sheets IMPORTRANGE bug? Multiple rows of missing data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, missing-data

I've got a Google Sheet with an IMPORTRANGE in cell A4, importing ~8000 rows of data from approximately 5 columns on another sheet.

This is the formula in A4:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL(redacted)","Reformatted Words!A4:E")
```

At row 2860 the data vanishes then picks back up row 5703.  The data is intact in the original spreadsheet.  I've included screenshots below showing this.

The data disappeared sometime after midnight last night, and others using this sheet have reported that the data spontaneously reappears for short periods of time.

I'd appreciate any help with this as I haven't been able to locate this behavior elsewhere on forums, etc.

Beginning of disappearance

[image: Beginning of disappearance]

End of disappearance

[image: End of disappearance]

Comment: It seems an internal issue, go to **Help > Sheets Help > Send Feedback** so you can get assisted by the Sheets Team.

Comment: or https://support.google.com/docs/community?hl=en